SSAS: General questions on dimension processing
Suppose I have a SSAS cube X which has two dimensions, A and B.
The processing of this cube is done daily as a SQL Server Agent Job. The job processing each dimension and the cube one-by-one, like this:
Step 1: Process (Update) Dimension A
Step 2: Process (Update) Dimension B
Step 3: Process Cube X
The current option used for processing dimensions is "Process Update".
My questions are:

I heard that "Process Full" is actually faster than "Process Update". If that's the case, why bother using "Process Update" at all? and if dimensions A and B are using "Process Full", is the step "Process Cube X" still necessary?

Is it true to say that "Process Full" = "Process Data" + "Process Index"? Would "process index" a dimension lock the cube from being accessed by users?


The SQL server version is 2008 R2. Thanks for your help in advance.
This is a question asking a general topic.
